# Load menus dynamically in Layout Page asp.net mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to load menu dynamically in layout page in mvc.

I have created Viewcode,model for menu and menuitems. Now what i want is i want to load the menus dynamically.It have to retreive data from database and load in Layout page.

**My model**

**Menu Model**

```
    public Menu()
    {
        MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
```

**My model MenuItem**

```
  public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Menu ParentMenu { get; set; }
}
```

**My controller**

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = db.ApplicationNames.ToList();
        ViewBag.Menu = query;
        return View();
    }
```

Now i have created model and controller code. Now i want further guidance that is how i show these application names in Layout page. And if i click the menu it have to redirect to that corresponding page.
Many of them said load menu in partial view and call that partial view in layout page. But how to load the menu in partial view and change that menus to ActionLink.I need some guidance and solution for this problem.Any one understand my issue and give solution for my problem.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send list of menus to the partial view let suppose i have data

```
var menu = new Menu();
menu.Name = "Main Menu";

var  items= new List<MenuItem>(){new MenuItem {Name="FirstMenu",ControllerName = "Home",ActionName="Index"}};

Menu.MenuItems = items;

   return View(menu);
```

now in my view i will add menu based on the given data

```
@model List<Models.Menu>

 <ul>

                 <li>
                    <a href="#">

                        <span>@Model.Name</span>

                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems)
                        {
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action(@item.ActionName , @item.ControllerName )"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>@item.Name</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: usman i am getting error and you used manuall controller name anc action name can you tell me how to use database values in controller and pass to  view

Comment: it was just for example you have get data from database MenuItem will be populated with controller name and action name

Comment: My controller code                                                                                                               public ActionResult Index(){var menu = new Menu();  menu.Name = "Main Menu"; var query = db.ApplicationNames.Select(e => new { 
  UID=  e.UID,e.ApplicationName1  }).FirstOrDefault();var uid = query.UID.ToString();  var name = query.ApplicationName1;var items = new List<MenuItem>() { new MenuItem { Name = "FirstMenu", ControllerName = uid, ActionName = name }};
  menu.MenuItems = items;
            return PartialView("MenuLayout",menu);}}

Comment: This is my controller code can you tell me this is correct or not

Comment: Here i cant able to shoe image because i cant able to upload image

Comment: your controller looks fine are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes and error is e:\Task Tried\DynamicMenuLoading\DynamicMenuLoading\Views\Shared\_MenuLayout.cshtml(8): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid argumentse:\Task Tried\DynamicMenuLoading\DynamicMenuLoading\Views\Shared\_MenuLayout.cshtml(8): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: you should render like this @{ Html.RenderPartial("viewname); }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137888/discussion-between-usman-and-sneha-susan).

Comment: My PartialViewCode                                                                                                                                                                                                               model List<DynamicMenuLoading.Models.Menu>
 <ul> <li>
<a href="#"><span>@Model.Name</span></a>
<ul>@foreach (var item in Model.MenuItems){ <li><a href="@Url.Action(@item.ActionName , @item.ControllerName )"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>@item.Name</a></li>
} </ul> </li></ul>